# Laravel Homestead and Connection Refused. Retrying messages on Windows 10

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am trying to install homestead on windows 10 and I have this warning messages on start-up, I can ( vagrant ssh & ping ) the VB machine but the local website refuses connection.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.6.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead: Booting VM...
==> homestead: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
    homestead: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    homestead: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
==> homestead: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead: Setting hostname...
==> homestead: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead: /vagrant => D:/homestead
    homestead: /home/vagrant/code => D:/Homestead_Projects
==> homestead: Detected mount owner ID within mount options. (uid: 1000 guestpath: /home/vagrant/code)
==> homestead: Detected mount group ID within mount options. (gid: 1000 guestpath: /home/vagrant/code)
==> homestead: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> homestead: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to run this command, vagrant up command is just for installation, and your installation is successfully done you need to run this command.

Run this command, I think it should help you :

```
 vagrant provision
```

if you turn off your pc then you need to run this command.

```
 vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: Did you manage to run it under windows 10 ?, I have the message "Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue" on the firefox browser now.

Comment: On my machine, calling `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload` has an absolutely equivalent outcome. There is not a single thing `up` seems to do that `reload` doesn't. Can you elaborate on why you think `vagrant up` was just for installation? @AsimRaza

Comment: `vagrant up` is not just for installation.  It is the preferred way to start a box.  It will provision the first time if needed, and then simply start after that.  The whole CONCEPT of Vagrant is that you can do this and it figures out what is needed (hence the website www.vagrantup.com :)